# MKUserTrackingButton turns into a spinner when no permission is given for locations services

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, mkuserlocation

I have added Apple's new `MKUserTrackingButton` to my app on a map view. It works fine when the user has previously given permission to use location services (e.g. `CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse`).

[image: MKUserTrackingButton default]

However, when the user has denied permission or the permission status is undetermined, the **user tracking button turns into an activity indicator** (aka spinner) and never stops spinning.

[image: MKUserTrackingButton spinning without permission]

Instead, I would like to show the iOS permission alert like in the Apple Maps app or at least some kind of alert to give the user a hint why it's not working. Naturally, I also want the activity indicator to stops and to turn back into the default "compass needle" icon.

Unfortunately, `MKUserTrackingButton` is not a sublass of `UIButton` so I cannot add any targets to it and there seems to be no API to change the visual status of the button.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: did you find any solution,

Comment: No. I think there isn't any. I tried to come up with some other user-friendly way that ships around the problem, if I remember correctly...

Comment: I'm just not showing the button, if there is no location in locationManager. `locationManager.location`